# react-router + history.pushState not working

Tags: react-router

Can I get some help the proper setup of history library with react-router, the docs somewhere says that I have to use a mixin to use history from reactrouter but somewhere else tells me that I have to import history library to acomplish the task. It's so confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to import the history library if you are going to be changing the default settings for react-router and that's only for when you setup your router. Otherwise, you don't need to.

Regardless, to use history.pushState, you do need to use the mixin. If using React Router 1.0.0-rc3, you would do as follows (a simple example but should get the point across):

```html
var React   = require('react');
var History = require('react-router').History;

var Link = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ History ],
  _handleClick: function(){
    this.history.pushState(null, "/example-route");  
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this._handleClick}>
        Link
      </div>
    );
  },
});

module.exports = Link;
```

Comment: can you tell difference between this.history.pushState(null, "/example-route");  and this.history.pushState(null, "example-route");  .. i removed forward slash from the beginning of url ...

Comment: I don't know if it matters!